# php7 routing in app engine fails in local environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

According to the docs found here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#application_startup

My app, is able to serve up index.php, without defining any handlers in my app.yaml file, which it does. Great! However, that same app.yaml file fails to serve up index in my local environment (dev_appserver.py) That seems less than ideal...

The path to the file is public/index.php

Here's the error I see in my local when I go with the very same app.yaml that works perfectly in production:

The url "/" does not match any handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The dev_appserver.py only works with the [first generation App Engine runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes).

As you can see on [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally), to test locally your PHP 7 app, you have to use the development tools that you usually use.

On [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/118756672) from the Google’s Public Issue Tracker there is a similar issue, and there is posted a solution for locally test PHP 7 apps. Basically, you have to set up a front controller on a web server locally. You can do it following [this tutorial](https://miloserdov.org/?p=55), for example.

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed response. I had noticed that dev_appserver.py was not mentioned in the tutorial. What I'm wondering is how to go about testing baked-in app engine services, such as memcache, locally, without having my local running on dev_appserver.py?

Comment: Memcache is [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences#migrating_from_the_app_engine_php_sdk) for second generation runtimes. Instead, it is recommended to use [Cloud Memorystore](https://issuetracker.google.com/113127309#comment7), but this can’t be tested locally, as you need to use a VPC connector.